# On the uncountability of a subset of U-numbers of type $\leq m$

Tags: nt.number-theory

We say that $\xi\in \mathbb{R}$ is an $m$-ultra number if there exists a sequence $(\alpha_n)_n$ of $m$-degree real algebraic numbers, such that
$$
|\xi-\alpha_n|<(\exp^{[3]}(H(\alpha_n)))^{-n},\ \mbox{for all}\ n
$$
where $H(\alpha_n)$ is the height of $\alpha_n$ (maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients of its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$) and $\exp^{[3]}(x)$ is the $3$-iterated of the exponential function.

Set $U_{m-ultra}$ as the set of all these numbers. In particular, $U_{m-ultra}$ is a subset of $U$-numbers of type at most $m$.

I would like to know if $U_{m-ultra}$ is uncountable or even more, if it is a $G_{\delta}$-dense set.